# Using operator ""s for std::chrono with gcc

Tags: gcc, c++-chrono, user-defined-literals

I want to use the [`std::chrono::duration` literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration), such as `10s` to mean "10 seconds", like this:

```
std::chrono::duration<uint64_t, std::milli> millisecs = 10s;
```

But, I'm getting this error:

> ```
> main.cpp:20:17: error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""s'
>      millisecs = 20s; 
> main.cpp:22:17: note: use -std=gnu++11 or -fext-numeric-literals to enable more built-in suffixes
> ```

I already added `-fext-numeric-literals` to my gcc compilation command:

```sh
g++ -fext-numeric-literals --std=c++17 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra \
    main.cpp -O0 -g -o go
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the appropriate "using namespace" directives?

Comment: @Mat: Which namespace is used for the operators?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s

Comment: @Mat: OK, got the point. Thanks! Make it answer to accept it ;)

Answer (score 7):

You should add the corresponding `namespace`:

```
 using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

Comment: 'chrono_literals' is not a namespace-name

Comment: What do you mean? What is that then?!

Comment: Exception, that was thrown after a namespace addition. From other threads I found it not compatible with older C++ versions (<=11)

Answer (score 0):

### Don't forget a `using namespace` declaration to get access to `std::chrono::duration<>` literals

I did some playing around and learning that you can take a look at here: [**chrono_duration_literals__using_declaration.cpp**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/cpp/chrono_duration_literals__using_declaration.cpp).

Key takeaways:

To use `std::chrono::duration<>` literals like `30s` for "30 seconds", ex: in this statement here:

```cpp
std::chrono::seconds halfmin = 30s;
```

...you must use the appropriate `using namespace` declaration, such as:

```cpp
// Use at least **one** of these!:
using namespace std::literals;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;  // [my preference]
using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
using namespace std::chrono;
```

...OR you can leave out those `using namespace` declarations, but then you must explicitly cast the integer to a `std::chrono::duration<>` type, like this, for example, to `std::chrono::seconds`, which is a typedef of `std::chrono::duration<int64_t, ratio<1, 1>>`:

```cpp
std::chrono::seconds halfmin = std::chrono::seconds(30);
```

My main source for learning about the 4 `using namespace` options above was here: [std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""s](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22s). This is the page for the `s` literal operator, for seconds. This operator is called `operator""s()`.

Anyway, that cppreference.com community wiki states some really valuable information (emphasis added):

> #### Notes
>
> These operators are declared in the namespace `std::literals::chrono_literals`, where both `literals` and `chrono_literals` are `inline` namespaces. **Access to these operators can be gained with `using namespace std::literals`, `using namespace std::chrono_literals`, and `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals`.**
>
> **In addition, within the namespace `std::chrono`, the directive `using namespace literals::chrono_literals;` is provided by the standard library, so that if a programmer uses `using namespace std::chrono`; to gain access to the classes in the `chrono` library, the corresponding literal operators become visible as well.**
>
> `std::string` also defines `operator""s`, to represent literal objects of type `std::string`, but it is a string literal: `10s` is ten seconds, but `"10"s` is a two-character string.

### If you leave out the `using namespace` declaration, you have these crazy-long casting options

All of these options work too, withOUT including a `using namespace` declaration from above, but they are pretty irritating to use:

```cpp
std::chrono::seconds halfmin = (std::chrono::seconds)30; // WORKS!
std::chrono::seconds halfmin = std::chrono::seconds(30); // WORKS! [My preference]
std::chrono::seconds halfmin = std::chrono::seconds{30}; // WORKS!

std::chrono::seconds halfmin = 
    std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1>>(30);   // WORKS!
std::chrono::seconds halfmin = std::chrono::duration<int64_t>(30); // WORKS!

auto halfmin = std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""s(30);    // WORKS!
std::chrono::duration<long double, std::ratio<1>> halfmin = 
    std::literals::chrono_literals::operator""s(30);               // WORKS!
std::chrono::seconds halfmin = 
    static_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(30);                         // WORKS!
std::chrono::seconds halfmin = 
    static_cast<std::chrono::duration<int64_t, std::ratio<1, 1>>>(30); // WORKS!
```

### If you're looking for C-like simplicity instead of `std::chrono`

...then use my `millis()`, `micros()`, and `nanos()` functions instead!

Then you can get super-simple timestamps like this:

```cpp
// millisecond timestamp with monotonic clock in C or C++
uint64_t time_ms = millis();

// microsecond timestamp with monotonic clock in C or C++
uint64_t time_us = micros();

// nanosecond timestamp with monotonic clock in C or C++
uint64_t time_ns = nanos();
```

#### See my answers and libraries:

1. [Here is how to get simple C-like millisecond, microsecond, and nanosecond timestamps in C++:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49066369/4561887)
2. [How to get a simple timestamp in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67731965/4561887)
3. My Linux C and C++ [`timinglib.h`](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/timinglib.h) timestamp and timing library. It has some *really convenient* `sleep` and `sleep_until` functions as well, and allows you turn on the soft real-time `SCHED_RR` round-robin scheduler in Linux too, to improve sleep resolution in x86-64 Linux from ~55 us to ~4 us.

   1. I keep this library up-to-date, and use it a lot. It's great.
   2. [timinglib.h](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/timinglib.h)
   3. [timinglib.c](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/timinglib.c)
4. 10 KHz periodic loop example of mine on Linux using my `sleep_until_us()` function: [How to run a high-resolution, high-precision periodic loop in Linux easily, at any frequency (ex: 10 KHz) using a soft real-time scheduler and nanosecond delays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71790209/4561887)

Comment: What's wrong with `auto halfmin = std::chrono_seconds(30);` ? It's missing in your non-using namespace examples...